# How to handle the KeyError in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to do some data analysis in Python, whereby I am trying to use some Twitter data to find the number of tweets of different countries. This is the code I am using :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data=[]
with open('/home/surya/tweet.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
     try:
       tweet= json.loads(line)
       tweets_data.append(tweet)
     except:
       continue

tweet_table= pd.DataFrame()
tweet_table['country']= map(lambda tweet: tweet["place"]["country"] if tweet["place"] != None else None, tweets_data)

tweets_by_country = tweet_table['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
```

This was generating an error

```
KeyError "place"
```

So I modified the code into something like this :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tweets_data=[]

 def keyCheck(key,arr,default):
   if key in arr.keys():
      return arr[key]
   else:
      return default

with open('/home/surya/tweet.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
     try:
       tweet= json.loads(line)
       tweets_data.append(tweet)
     except:
       continue

tweet_table= pd.DataFrame()
tweet_table['country']= map(lambda tweet: tweet["place"]["country"] if keyCheck("place",tweet,"#default") != None else None, tweets_data)

tweets_by_country = tweet_table['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
```

But this resulted in the error

```
AttributeError: list object has no attribute "keys"
```

The format of my data is:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jun 16 13:15:13 +0000 2016","id":743431739238932480,"id_str":"743431739238932480","text":"I fucking hate Ramsey #ENGWAL #EURO2016 https:\/\/t.co\/wkFqOu8iwf","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":343618050,"id_str":"343618050","name":"SamuEars","screen_name":"S88Griff","location":"Derbados","url":null,"description":"27 years old, @RocesterFC1876 footballer, genuine, chilled out, opinionated, but most of all, wind up merchant","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":496,"friends_count":272,"listed_count":1,"favourites_count":1915,"statuses_count":5505,"created_at":"Wed Jul 27 20:53:02 +0000 2011","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/636136111191031809\/aQyj3bgK_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/636136111191031809\/aQyj3bgK_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/343618050\/1409857726","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"232163114ebb8671","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/232163114ebb8671.json","place_type":"city","name":"Etwall","full_name":"Etwall, England","country_code":"GB","country":"United Kingdom","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-1.608732,52.874969],[-1.608732,52.887677],[-1.594409,52.887677],[-1.594409,52.874969]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"ENGWAL","indices":[22,29]},{"text":"EURO2016","indices":[30,39]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":743431733853433856,"id_str":"743431733853433856","indices":[40,63],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClEzORsWMAAlcQ3.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClEzORsWMAAlcQ3.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/wkFqOu8iwf","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/wkFqOu8iwf","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/S88Griff\/status\/743431739238932480\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":517,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1178,"h":896,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":1178,"h":896,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":743431733853433856,"id_str":"743431733853433856","indices":[40,63],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClEzORsWMAAlcQ3.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClEzORsWMAAlcQ3.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/wkFqOu8iwf","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/wkFqOu8iwf","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/S88Griff\/status\/743431739238932480\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":517,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1178,"h":896,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":1178,"h":896,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1466082913585"}
```

The problem it seems is that **"place"** key is not available somewhere in my **tweet.txt** file.

Can someone suggest a solution to it or please point out where exactly I am going wrong?

**EDIT**

I just updated the code into this

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

tweets_data=[]
with open('/home/surya/tweet.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
     try:
        tweet= json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
     except:
        continue

tweet_table= pd.DataFrame()
tweet_table['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if 'place' in tweet is not None and 'country' in tweet['place'] is not None else None, tweets_data)

tweets_by_country = tweet_table['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
```

And now I get this error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

**UPDATE**

Just found the solution. Appending the tweets_data only when 'place' in tweet is not None. Hence

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data=[]
with open('/home/surya/tweet.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
     try:
        tweet= json.loads(line)
        if 'place' in tweet is not None:
           tweets_data.append(tweet)
     except:
        continue

tweet_table= pd.DataFrame()
tweet_table['country'] = [tweet['place']['country'] for tweet in tweets_data if tweet['place']]

tweets_by_country = tweet_table['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `if 'place' in tweet`

Comment: I replaced if tweet['place'] with if 'place' in tweet and now the error comes 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
'

Comment: Btw your entire keyCheck function has already been implemented in python. Just use `dict_name.get("key", "defaultValue")`

Comment: Also is your actual file a json list containing many of items like the one example you've shown?

Comment: @Keatinge yes it contains about 21000 tweets. The one I have posted is just one of the many.

Comment: @CodeRabbit I know, I'm wondering about the format, can you show what you file looks like with two tweets? You're json.loading each line individually which I'm almost positive is wrong, but it's possible your file format is actually a new json string per line. Or even upload your entire file to pastebin

Comment: @Keatinge File is around 119.2 MB

Comment: @CodeRabbit Copy and paste enough into pastebin to include 5-10 tweets and that will be fine. I just need to know if you have a new tweet per line and if they are in one big enclosing list. It's not possible to answer your question without knowing the data structure enclosing the tweets

Comment: @Keatinge http://pastebin.com/4yjX2E8j the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    tweet_data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

tweet_table= pd.DataFrame()

tweet_table['country'] = [tweet['place']['country'] for tweet in tweet_data if tweet['place']]

tweets_by_country = tweet_table['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Okay I found the problem, it's that the tweet always contains a place as a key in the json, it's just that place will be null if there is no place, so you just have to ensure place isn't null before you try to access country. This is working for me, but I'm only getting UK because the data only has 1 tweet with a country